# Растянуть текст при пропорциональном растягивании родителя

Tags: javascript, css

Есть `div`с изначально определённым размером; див содержит текст `<p>`, с также изначально определённым размером шрифта. Мне нужно чтобы при пропорциональном изменении размеров `div` размер текста изменялся соответственно. Пропорциональное изменение див происходит так:

1.Сохраняется отношение оригинальной ширины к высоте.

2.Произвольно меняется **ширина**

3.Новая высота = новая ширина/отношение оригинальной ширины к высоте.

Что пытаюсь делать я:

После изменения размеров дива, получаю размер шрифта через компьтед стайл, дальше в зависимости от того уменьшился ли родительский див или увеличился, запускаю цикл в котором уменьшаю/увеличиваю шрифт на один, пока обтекающий(неявно) его прямоугольник не входит в рамки/выходит за рамки див; уменьшаю размер шрифта на 1, чтобы получить значение перед входом/выходом за рамки дива.

Высоту обтекающего текст прямоугольника нахожу через эту функцию(ширину аналогично):

```
function getTextNodeHeight(textNode) {
var height = 0;
if (document.createRange) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
    if (range.getBoundingClientRect) {
        var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (rect) {
            height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        }
    }
}
return height;
}
```

Передаю в неё не `<p>` а див в котором `<p>` находится.

Структура

```
 <div style="position:absolute;left:...;top:..;width:..;height:...">
 <p style="position: absolute">любой текст даже с <br></p>
 </div>
```

Сам див находится в другом див а тот в другом и т.д..

Comment: А не проще один раз отрендерить текст через Canvas, в изображение с `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;`? Чем постоянно его "пересчитывать"...

Comment: @yar85 подумаю над этим, но уже вроде работает, хотя концептуально механизм не менял, просто после тысячного «перекомпилирования» вроде стало работать как надо

Comment: Интересно :) Кстати, еще один вариант "в копилку" - можно склонировать сам элемент с текстом (спрятав его через абсолютное позиционирование за пределы вьюпорта) и в нем подбирать размер шрифта, проверяя фактический размер - это надежнее, и скорее всего, окажется значительно быстрее (так как меняется только один стиль, и без рефлоу на каждой итерации).

Comment: Еще есть специальный интерфейс `TextMetrics`, как раз для измерения габаритов текста... но перенос стилей на Canvas иногда сложнее, чем измерение через невидимый клон элемента, да и поддержка браузерами пока что неполная.